# Update query not working in heroku

Tags: jquery, laravel, heroku, jeditable

I'm using this inline editor js plugin

```
$('.edit').editable('/update', {
 // type     : 'textarea',
 // onblur   : 'submit',
 event: 'click',
 indicator : 'saving ...',
 select : true,
 submitdata : function(value, settings) {
   return {_method: "PUT",_token:token,col:$(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1]};
 },callback : function(value, settings) {
     $(this).addClass('success');
 }
 });
```

The `col:$(this).attr("class").split(' ')` is the one i am passing to

```
Route::put('/update', function(Request $request){
 DB::update("UPDATE patients SET " . $request['col'] . " = ? WHERE PatientID = ?", [$request->value, $request->id]);

});
```

I used `$request['col']` to dynamically change the column to be updated base on the class of the element which is `col:$(this).attr("class").split(' ')`

It's all working fine when I'm in local development but when I try to host it in heroku I'm getting an internal server error

So I have tried changing the query to`DB::update("UPDATE patients SET patient_fname = ? WHERE PatientID = ?", [$request->value, $request->id]);` so the column is just static, then it works just fine but i want to change the column dynamically.

Comment: It's all covered in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#updates).

Comment: I know about that it doesnt work too so i tried using a raw query so i can see what really is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make a `patient` eloquent model. and by doing that you can just type

```
Patient::update($values);
```

Comment: where can i specify what column?

Comment: its by default will map the request parameters with the column in the model. let say you sent {"name": "my name"}, laravel will take "name" and search for column called "name" and update its value

Comment: i have tried `Patient::update($request['col']);` and `Patient::update($request->value);` none of it works